# How to send an ArrayList of IR codes?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, infrared

I have a list of TV IR codes that I listed into an `ArrayList<int[]>`

But I don't have much Android infrared blaster experience, so how would I send the `ArrayList<int[]>` of IR data on the press of the button?

Comment: a quick google search resulted in this http://www.irdroid.com/ looks like they are open source.

Comment: The IR blasters that are built into devices seem to be somewhat manufacturer specific. I know that HTC, and LG both provide their own APIs that are specific to their devices. AFAIK the system does not have its own API, and thus it is left up to the device manufacturer to expose a way for developers to interact with it. So you should start by looking on the developer page for your device manufacturer for their IR SDK.

Comment: Try the answer from this question, and let me know: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28934938/1042362