# ConsumerIrManager not working on HTC m8 lollipop

Tags: api, infrared, htc-android

before the official lollipop update ConsumerIrManager was working fine with the HTC m8 (And so did the official HTC IR samples from htcdev) -

After update it doesnt work anymore

ConsumerIrManager gives Error-16

any idea what HTC may have changed?

Comment: This is a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794899/ir-emitter-and-android-5-0/28934938#28934938

Comment: Hi, this is not duplicate, on HTC M8 Lollipop  it ALWAYS throws error -16. On other lollipop devices i have no issue, then what you posted is true

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue on the HTC One M7 once updated to Lollipop. I pulled some JARs and APKs from the phone and decompiled them to found that they are not using the ConsumerIrManager like every device is doing since Android 4.4. Worst, they rolled back and use the same libraries they were using before 4.4. In my case, I rolled back my implementation using the HTC IR API (see https://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk/htc-ir-api), and my code is now working.

Comment: Hi, I cannot seem to get the IR transmitter to even turn on with the HTC one after Lollipop update. You said you got it working? Could you please help me. I am so upset. I import the sample project from the official htc sdk and right off the bat the sample doesnt even do anything. Could you please help me get it to work? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

unless the issue is related to:
[HTC ONE M8 IR Blaster after Lollipop Update not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021453/htc-one-m8-ir-blaster-after-lollipop-update-not-working)

please note that the HTC IR APIs (with Lollipop / Sense 7) is now deprecated (technically removed) - note they are already under the legacy APIs section.