# HTC IR API Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, infrared

I am trying to get the infrared transmitter to work on the HTC ONE m8 after lollipop update. I am trying to use the HTC Sense IR SDK (addon-htc_ir_api-htc-19) found here: http://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk/htc-ir-api I import the sample project (HTCConsumerIR) and run the app on my HTC device and the app simply does not transmit a signal. I get no errors, but the infrared transmitter does not even turn on. This is the same project with no modifications at all. Why is it not working? Any help from someone who has infrared working on HTC would be much appropriated. It can get infrared working on every device except HTC's.

Here is the code for the main class, if that helps at all:

```
      public class OneCIRActivity extends Activity {

    private final static String TAG = "OneCIR";
    private boolean running;

    ConsumerIrManagerCompat mCIR;
    Button btnLearn, btnSend, btnSendByIRManager, btnStart, btnStop;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_onecir);

        btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonstart);
        //        btnStart.setOnClickListener(btnStartListener); //HTC optional (see onResume())
        //        btnStart.setText("CIRControl.start");
        btnStart.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        btnLearn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonlearn);
        btnLearn.setOnClickListener(btnLearnListener);
        btnLearn.setText("Learn IR"); //HTC

        btnSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonsend);
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(btnSendIRListener);
        btnSend.setText("Send IR"); //BOTH

        btnStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonstop);
        //        btnStop.setOnClickListener(btnStopListener); //HTC optional 
        //        btnStop.setText("CIRControl.stop");
        btnStop.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);

        mCIR = ConsumerIrManagerCompat.createInstance(getApplicationContext());

        mCIR.start(); //for HTC - noop otherwise (also see onResume()/onPause() )

        mCIR.setTextView(textView); // to pass errors to UI

        updateUI();
    }


    public void updateUI() {
        if (mCIR != null) {
            if (mCIR.hasIrEmitter()) {
                    if((mCIR.supportedAPIs|ConsumerIrManagerCompat.HTCSUPPORT)!=0) {
                        btnLearn.setEnabled(true);
                    } else {
                        btnLearn.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    btnSend.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                btnLearn.setEnabled(false);
                btnSend.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_onecir, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private OnClickListener btnLearnListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Use this HTC API to learn any IR function from remote controller
            mCIR.learnIRCmd(10); // set 10sec timeout
            textView.setText("Learning for 10 seconds");
        }       
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(!mCIR.isStarted()) {
            mCIR.start(); //needed for HTC API (noop otherwise) before calling other APIs
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(mCIR.isStarted()) {
            mCIR.stop(); //needed for HTC API (noop otherwise)
        }
    }

    private OnClickListener btnSendIRListener = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (!running) {
                btnSend.setEnabled(false);
                running = true;
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(ConsumerIrManagerCompat.PREFERENCE_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        // default IR data example from a laptop's ir remote: right button
                        int[] frame = {340,172,22,22,22,65,22,65,22,65,22,22,22,65,22,65,22,65,22,65,22,65,22,64,22,23,22,22,22,22,22,23,22,65,22,22,22,65,22,65,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,23,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,64,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,23,22,1600,341,86,22,3677,341,86,22,367};
                        int frequency = preferences.getInt(ConsumerIrManagerCompat.PREFERENCE_KEY_FREQUENCY, 38000);
                        // otherwise use last learned code
                        String framesaved = preferences.getString(ConsumerIrManagerCompat.PREFERENCE_KEY_FRAME, null);
                        if(framesaved!=null ) {
                            StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(framesaved.substring(1, framesaved.length()-2), ",");
                            int num = tok.countTokens();
                            if(num>0) {
                                frame = new int[num];
                                int index = 0;
                                while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                    frame[index++] = Integer.parseInt(tok.nextToken().trim());
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        mCIR.transmit(frequency, frame);

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        running = false;
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() {btnSend.setEnabled(true);}});
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        }
    };    
/*
    private OnClickListener btnStartListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //HTC CIR commands are only allowed after using this start() method.
            mCIR.start();
            text1.setText("Attached to CIR control service");
            updateUI();
        }

    };
    private OnClickListener btnStopListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO: before doing this, developer must make sure pending CIR commands.
            //will be handled if they had been sent to HTC CIR. 
            mCIR.stop();
            text1.setText("Detached from CIR control service");
            updateUI();
        }
    };
*/
    //TODO: HTC: Use this method to cancel sending IR command and learning IR command
    // Example: Before learning IR activity finishes, cancel command can stop it.
    // Example: If send an IR command with repeat count 255, cancel command can stop it. 
    //
    // mCIR.cancelCommand();
```

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021453/htc-one-m8-ir-blaster-after-lollipop-update-not-working?rq=1

Comment: He says to use the htc api, which is what I am trying to do but cant figure out :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HtcConsumerIr app doesn't work on Lollipop because it only uses the HTC library if you have KitKat.
If you open ConsumerIrManagerCompat.java and change this line:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT
                              && hasPackage("com.htc.cirmodule", context)) {
        return new ConsumerIrManagerHtc(context);
    } else {
        return new ConsumerIrManagerBase(context);
    }
```

to this:

```
if (hasPackage("com.htc.cirmodule", context)) {
        return new ConsumerIrManagerHtc(context);
    } else {
        return new ConsumerIrManagerBase(context);
    }
```

it will work.

I'm currently trying to get my app working again after upgrading to Lollipop. It was all working fine in KitKat without needing to use the HTC library.
I've not got it completely working yet, but I have got it transmitting. Seems we're back to using pulse counts instead of durations too.