# ConsumerIrManager.transmit broken in Lollipop?

Tags: android, infrared

I upgraded my Samsung Galaxy S4 from latest KitKat to Lollipop (5.0.1) yesterday and my IR remote control app that I have used for months stopped working.

Since I was using a late copy of KitKat ConsumerIrManager, the transmit( ) function was sending the number of pulses using the code below.  It worked very nicely.

```
private void irSend(int freqHz, int[] pulseTrainInMicroS) {
  int [] pulseCounts = new int [pulseTrainInMicroS.length];

  for (int i=0; i<pulseTrainInMicroS.length; i++) {
    long iValue = pulseTrainInMicroS[i] * freqHz / 1000000;
    pulseCounts[i] = (int) iValue;
  } 

  m_IRService.transmit(freqHz, pulseCounts);
}
```

when it stopped working yesterday, I began looking closely at it.

I noticed that the transmitted waveform is not having any relationship with the requested pulse train.  even the code below doesn't work correctly!  there is

```
private void TestSend() {
  int [] pulseCounts = {100, 100, 100};

  m_IRService.transmit(38000, pulseCounts);
}
```

the resulting waveforms had many problems and so are entirely useless.

- the waveforms were entirely wrong
- the frequency was wrong and the pulse spacing was not regular
- they were not repeatable

looking at the demodulated waveform:
if my 100, 100, 100 were correctly rendered, I should have seen two pulses 2.6ms (before 4.4.3(?) 100 us) long.  instead I received (see attached) "[demodulated] not repeatable 1.BMP" and "[demodulated] not repeatable 2.BMP".  note that the waveform isn't 2 pulses...in fact, it's not even repeatable.

as for the captures below, the signal goes low when the IR is detected.

[image: wrong and not repeatable]

[image: wrong and not repeatable]

we should have seen two pulses going low for 2.6 ms and 2.6 ms between them (see green line below).

[image]

I had also tried shorter pulses using 50, 50, 50 and have observed that the first pulse isn't correct either (see below).

[image]

looking at the modulated waveform:
the frequency was not correct; instead, it was about 18kHz and irregular.

[image: wrong frequency and irregular]

I'm quite experienced with this and have formal education in electronics.

It seems to me there's a bug in ConsumerIrManager.transmit( )...

curiously, the "WatchOn" application that comes with the phone still works.

thank you for any insights you can give.

Test equipment:
Tektronix TDS-2014B, 100 MHz, used in peak-detect mode.

Comment: This is the answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794899/ir-emitter-and-android-5-0/28934938#28934938

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @IvanTellez says, a change was made in Android in respect to this functionality.  Strangely, when I had it outputting simple IR signals (for troubleshooting purposes), the function behaves as shown above (erratically, wrong carrier frequency, etc).  When I eventually returned to normal types of IR signals, it worked correctly.