# How to send custom IR patterns on Android devices - Samsung, LG, HTC, Sony, Huawei?

Tags: java, android, infrared

Samsung devices supports Google Infrared API (ConsumerIrManager).
LG and HTC released own libraries: HTC IR API and LG QRemote SDK

I created a ***open project on GitHub*** which implements possibility to send custom IR patterns:
https://github.com/OneButtonDeveloper/AndroidInfraRed

but it works only with Samsung and LG devices:

On my HTC, it works without any exceptions but without any result too.
Please, take a look on [HtcTransmitter.java](https://github.com/OneButtonDeveloper/AndroidInfraRed/blob/master/infrared/src/main/java/com/obd/infrared/transmit/concrete/HtcTransmitter.java)

Devices with IR: HTC One M7 ... M9

**Sony & Huawei** Not supported sending custom IR patterns at all?
Devices with IR: Sony Xperia ZL, Huawei Honor 6

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794899/ir-emitter-and-android-5-0/28934938#28934938